# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES Handling without Uninstalling?

Tags: android, signed-apk, android-studio-2.3

**I am re-posting this question because I found nothing from other previous answers** asked by others.

All are saying  **"Uninstall previous app and Install new"**.

**But What I want is:**   I am `upgrading` my app `Version`, While I am `installing` it to device from `android Studio` Its showing Above error [`INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES`].

So, My Question is, How to `Install` new `upgraded` app over my old app **without** `Uninstalling`.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to update an app with the same package name but with a different certificate.

To perform an app update both the package name and the certificate must match.

The ONLY option if they do not match is to uninstall and then reinstall as the other questions you saw probably said.

Comment: So, there is no other solution than Uninstalling ?

Comment: already asked and answered

Comment: So, Signed Apk is also not an option you are saying?